# Scope for Public and Private

Tags: c++, class, scope, private, public

There is a piece of code:

```
class BirdCarreau: public viscosityModel  // Private data
{


        dictionary BirdCarreauCoeffs_;
...
```

Why this data which is inside this PUBLIC type is said to be private data?

Comment: Are you asking why the `private` data members of `viscosityModel` aren't visible to `BirdCarreau`?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance.

Comment: That's not a ‘*public type*’, it's a class that publicly inherits from an other class. Any C++ book worth its name will teach you this.

Comment: You are confusing inheritance with access specifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example **public** means that **BirdCarreau** inherit the data and methods from **viscosityModel**.So **public** is used to achieve public inheritance.By default, all members of a class have private access. So, the data in your class is
private.

Answer (score 1):

Default access protection for members in a class is private. So you need to put `public:` before.

The `public` you provided is only for the base class. But your members are extending the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

The class itself is public but its members are private to the user. That's the general idea of classes. you can make them public by specifically stating their access modifier to be private